# Change navigationdrawer item language

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

In my android app I want to change language form fragment.My app contains MainActivity.java. This activity contains navigation drawer and fragment. When I change my locale from fragment, language is changed every where but not in navigation drawer.I am using code

```
private String setLocal() {
    Locale locale;
    Resources res = getResources();
    DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
    Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
    prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Language", 0);
    String restoredText = prefs.getString("language", "");
    if (restoredText.equalsIgnoreCase("fr_FR"))
        locale = new Locale("fr");

    else
        locale = new Locale("en");
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    conf = new Configuration();
    res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);

    return restoredText;
}
```

When i select English I get following result[image: in English]

after changing language I get this one

[image]
here is string file from values-fr directory

```
 <string-array name="nav_drawer_titles">
    <item>Accueil</item>
    <item>Profil</item>
    <item>courses</item>
    <item>Tarification</item>
    <item>Configuration</item>
    <item>Envoyez à un ami</item>
    <item>Facture</item>
    <item>Position du Chaufeur</item>
    <item>Aide</item>
    <item>Déconnexion</item>
</string-array>
```

and here from values folder

```
 <!-- Nav Drawer Menu Items -->
<string-array name="nav_drawer_titles">
    <item>Home</item>
    <item>Profile</item>
    <item>Ride Log</item>
    <item>Invoice</item>
    <item>Track Chauffeur</item>
    <item>Language</item>
    <item>Refer To Friend</item>
    <item>Help</item>
    <item>Sign Out</item>
</string-array>
```

and my navigationdrawerfragnet is

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    title = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_titles);

    images = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);


    mDrawerListView = (ListView) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);


    mDrawerListView
            .setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    selectItem(position);
                }
            });
    selectedposition = new int[] { mCurrentSelectedPosition };
    drawerAdapter = new CustomDrawerAdapter(getActivity(), title, images,
            selectedposition);

    mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(mCurrentSelectedPosition, true);
    mDrawerListView.setAdapter(drawerAdapter);
    return mDrawerListView;
}
```

Im MainActivity.java

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
    setLocal();
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    setLocal();
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
}
```

Comment: You should change in your activity which contains youe menu drawer.

Comment: ok i change it on main activity but not getting desirede result

Comment: i think your menudrawer item's strings should also be in strings.xml, are they in it ?

Comment: In All other is it working fine ?

Comment: @piyush yes in other fragments and activity its wirking fine

Comment: @Bhushan yes I have in string file

Comment: please see my updated post

Comment: can you show your code of using the string array? you need to invalidate your list menu item adapter

Comment: @ Linh please tell how  do that, i will try

Comment: where do you use the string array? show me that lines

Comment: @RahulPatel on your language selection event call getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu(); might be solution.

Comment: can you explain me, I am not using the adapter manually I created then inside the onresume I updated the UI but not changing

Answer (score 3):

You should set your locale in your drawer activity before `setContentView(int resId)`.

Also in `onResume()` method you can recrate your activity with `API_LEVEL >= 11`
call `super.recreate()` and below `11` you can set `onCreate(null)`.

Comment: in main activity or in navigation drawer fragment i am using api level 11

Comment: @RahulPatel Did u check ?

Comment: yes please see my updated question, but not able to change

Answer (score 0):

check [this](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html#top)

```
title = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_titles);

images = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

   mDrawerListView
        .setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                selectItem(position);
            }
        });
selectedposition = new int[] { mCurrentSelectedPosition };
drawerAdapter = new CustomDrawerAdapter(getActivity(), title, images,
        selectedposition);

mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(mCurrentSelectedPosition, true);
mDrawerListView.setAdapter(drawerAdapter);
```

you need to push there line on your setLocal method to invalidate drawer list

Comment: you need to invalidate your drawerAdapter  to update string array. just copy there lines above to your setLocal method

Comment: in navigation drawer fragment